# $T \circ R=R \circ T$ for Linear Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T,R: V \rightarrow V$ be two linear maps of rank 1 with the same kernel and the same image.  Prove that $T \circ R=R \circ T$.

I cannot use the rank/nullity theorem since $V$ is not necessarily finite-dimensional?. Do I have to prove that $T \circ R= (T \circ R)^{-1}$? How do I proceed? any hints

Comment: Can you prove that $T, R$ are constant multiples of each other?

Answer (score 1):

We have $T(v) = \varphi(v)w_1$ for some $0 \neq w_1 \in V$ and $0 \neq \varphi \in V^{*}$. Similarly, $R(v) = \psi(v)w_2$ for some $0 \neq w_2 \in V$ and $0 \neq \psi \in V^{*}$. If $T$ and $R$ have the same image, then $w_2 = \lambda w_1$ for some $0 \neq \lambda \in \mathbb{F}$. If $T$ and $R$ have the same kernel, then

$$ \ker \varphi = \ker T = \ker R = \ker \psi $$

so $\psi = \mu \varphi$ for some $0 \neq \mu \in \mathbb{F}$. Thus,

$$ R(v) = \lambda \mu \varphi(v) w_1 = \lambda \mu T(v) $$

so $R = cT$ for $0 \neq c = \lambda \mu$. This immediately implies that $R$ and $T$ commute.